# Incorrect data in response to AT commands (SIM7000C MQTT)

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, mqtt, uart, at-command

I am using SIM7000C NB-IoT HAT with Raspberry Pi 3 B+.
When requesting AT commands MQTT I quite often get incorrect response data.

Let's take the AT+SMCONN command (connecting to MQTT) as an example

I expect to get OK or ERROR, but I often get incomprehensible bytes.
[image]

I also get this error when sending MQTT messages and subscribing to tops. Sometimes this behavior loops and sending a message becomes impossible.
I also note that in response to a particular command, I get the same bytes of data in an incorrect response.

With commands that do not involve networking, this error does not occur.

To send AT commands I used minicom as indicated in the documentation. Also I tried changing the baud rate and using pyserial.

P.S.
I apologize if I put unnecessary tags. I'm not sure where best to put my question((

Comment: I should also add that sometimes, after receiving such a response, the ability to write to the port is lost. I have to close the connection and open it again.

Comment: Could you try to capture the output with [atinout](https://atinout.sourceforge.net/): `atinout file_with_the_at_commands.txt /dev/ttyS0 output.txt` and then post `hexdump -c output.txt`?

Comment: I have not been able to get atinout to work with this hat. I also tried 
```echo AT | socat - /dev/ttyS0,crnl``` and got no results. The modem is not responding.